# Add attributes to rootNode when using XMLViews

Tags: xml, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, xml-attribute

I am looking for a way to add attributes for the root node when using XMLViews in CakePHP3. The Script generates a simple sitemap.xml which needs the namespace included in the `urlset` tag. Not to much code to show, but anyway:

```php
function sitemap($language='en') {
    [..]
    $_rootNode = 'urlset';
    $this->set(compact('url'));
    $this->set('_rootNode', $_rootNode);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['url']);
}
```

I am aware, that I could add *real* views for the XML, but I would prefer this way of doing this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally attributes can be defined using the `@` prefix. In case of a generic namespace you could also use the `xmlns:` key.

In order to add them to the root note, you have to set them as view/serialization variables at the same level as the `url` variable, ie something like

```php
$attributes = [
    'xmlns:' => 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9', // or
    // '@xmlns' => 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9',
    // ...
];
$this->set($attributes + compact('url'));
$this->set('_rootNode', $_rootNode);
$this->set('_serialize', array_merge(array_keys($attributes), ['url']));
```

So that you end up with a dataset that looks like

```php
[
    'xmlns:' => 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9',
    // ...
    'url' => [
        // ...
    ]
]
```

and a serialization set like

```php
['xmlns:' /*, ... */, 'url']
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > XML > Transforming an Array into a String of XML](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/xml.html#transforming-an-array-into-a-string-of-xml)**

Comment: thanks a lot! works as expected.. Took me a while to realize the difference regarding the `:`